# why is messageIdExpression needed in Aggregator router

Tags: mule

The mule documentation [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Splitter+Flow+Control+Reference) talk about how to set the `messageIdExpression` in the Aggregation router, my question is why would I need to set the `messageId` especially when it cannot be customised in the splitting process.

The section of the documentation I am confused about is:

```
<expression-message-info-mapping
            messageIdExpression="#[java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()]"
            correlationIdExpression="#[xpath3('//order/@id')]" />
```

The same documentation shows that the `messageId` is not used during the aggregation process or am I holding the wrong end of the stick here ?

[image: Correlation in Mule ESB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `expression-message-info-mapping` element configures the [`org.mule.routing.ExpressionMessageInfoMapping`](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.6.2/core/src/main/java/org/mule/routing/ExpressionMessageInfoMapping.java) class which takes care of both generating message IDs and message correlation IDs.

This has no default value for `messageIdExpression` so you need to configure both to be able to use it, even if in the case of aggregation, only the correlation ID is used for grouping messages.